# ASP.NET Plugin Model Question

Tags: asp.net

I have to create a new ASP.NET 3.5 site (Not MVC!), and I am required to build a Plugin Architecture for the same.

I am thinking of using UserControls, but DLL of the UserControl must be placed in "bin" directory in order for it to work :(. I can't do that becauase I will have lots of Dlls and want to load the DLLs dynamically when needed for the UserControl.

Is there a way to achieve it ?

So my requirements :

- Core will load Plugin UserControls depending on configuration
- DLL should be loaded on demand rather then from bin directory

Please help!

Comment: Why you decided to use UserControls, not custom controls?

Comment: Because UserControls are most easy to develop and UserControls are XCopy deployed. But if you have any concrete example of this using CustomControls please share

Comment: Are you using a workaround like this http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2005/10/30/487160.aspx to distribute user controls in DLLs? Yes this is possible, but this is only a workaround. By default, when you want to build a redistributable controls libraries, it is better to use Custom Controls though they are more hard to develop.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that in general Web Client Software factory will be able to solve your problems, however it will require some time to master. 
Please see these links in [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/websf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Getting%20Started) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304726.aspx) to start with.
What is you asking about "load on demand" is implemented as different Business modules in WCSF and you configure on web site what modules to load and what not. Business module is a combination of related Web pages, page flows, business logic, and services.

Comment: Looks pretty complicated, any other suggestions for simpler execution ? WCSF, seems overkill for my situation, i will use it only as a last resort.

Comment: really it may be a bit complicated but it addresses more complex issue of modular web site design. when you want to have pluggable modules you don't only want to include or exclude some custom controls. you need to include/exclude pages, include/exclude classes of DAL and business logic that are not required in this particular case and you need to rebuild sitemap and menu... and for some customers you would like to have some modifications in the Views and define what views you will use in web.config. that is why WCSF is complex :)